# Optimisation of React-Native app memory while fetching Data from network

Tags: axios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am working with a React-Native app and i have some FlatList Component inside it and it is using round bout 100MB of memory but the problem i am facing is when i make some network request and after getting response from network request it start using memory of near about 500MB but according to PostMan this service response size is 18.66KB I also have implemented pagination so when FlatList's scroll finishes i make another call but this time memory is not increasing rapidly as it was increasing previously.
I am using Redux-saga for state management and i also disptach and action in componentWillUnMount to clear the state of redux but app memory not clearing it at all.

[image]

and here is post man response time and size
[image]

Comment: Does your network response include links to images that are then kept in memory and rendered on screen?

Comment: yes @nbokmans, but if i only fetch one single object with links it also taking a lots of memory before rendering the image means if i only fetch the data and render nothing memory usage will also huge.